# Pygame : force playing next song in queue even if actual song isn't finished? (aka "Next" button)

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make with pygame the same functionalities as a walkman : play, pause , queuing is ok.But how to do the previous/next buttons?

How can I ,with pygame, force the play  of the next song which has been queued (and pass the ong which is actually playing?)

Comment: You need to include what you've tried, what doesn't work and what you expect it to do. Pygame has a [queue](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue) function but it only plays the next song if it ends naturally. So you have implement a queue system yourself if you want to be able to switch songs in the middle of one (or to the previous). It's not hard to implement yourself (it's basically a list, loading from the list and keeping track on the index of the list) but you have to show what you have tried first.

Comment: did you read PyGame documentation ? ie. [pygame.mixer.music](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html)

Comment: To extend: We need to know your current knowledge of the problem in order to provide an answer that doesn't go over fundamental python/pygame semantics (which is a waste of your and our time), and not an answer which is too hard for you to understand. If you give us a simple attempt we can quickly see what your starting point is and provide help. Maybe a link to the documentation is sufficient, or explain how to load songs from a list etc. That will narrow the question down and make it less broad and more answerable. It'll also show us that you don't just want the code, but actually learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a list of song titles, and keep track of where you are in the list with a variable. Whether you are using `pygame.mixer.music` or `pygame.mixer.Sound`, when the "next" button is clicked, just have the variable change by one, and then stop the song, and have song the variable corresponds to play instead.

Code example for `pygame.mixer.Sound`:

```
#setup pygame above this
#load sounds
sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("soundone.ogg")
sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("soundtwo.ogg")

queue = [sound1, sound2] #note that the list holds the sounds, not strings
var = 0

sound1.play()

while 1:
    if next(): #whatever the next button trigger is
        queue[var].stop() # stop current song
        if var == len(queue - 1): # if it's the last song
            var = 0 # set the var to represent the first song
        else:
            var += 1 # else, next song
        queue[var].play() # play the song var corresponds to
```

Comment: Sorry,I saw this just now.Thank you a lot.

Comment: @BénédicteLagouge It's fine, glad I could help! Tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This was an example i got working for myself to wrap my head around the behavior of the program.

```py
from os import environ
environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = '1'  # noqa This is used to hide the default pygame import print statement.
import pygame
import time

# Credit: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=102008

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((420, 240))  # Shows PyGame Window.

playlist = list()
playlist.append('/Music/Tom MacDonald - Angels (Explicit).mp3')
playlist.append('/Music/Falling In Reverse - Bad Girls Club (Explicit).mp3')

pygame.mixer.music.load(playlist.pop())               # Get the first track from the playlist
pygame.mixer.music.queue(playlist.pop())              # Queue the 2nd song
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.USEREVENT)     # Setup the end track event
pygame.mixer.music.play()                             # Play the music

running = True
while running:
    time.sleep(.1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:                # A track has ended
            if len(playlist) > 0:                         # If there are more tracks in the queue...
                pygame.mixer.music.queue(playlist.pop())  # Queue the next one in the list
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:                   # Create a way to exit the program.
            running = False
```